# vb.net richtextbox text selection from a to b

Tags: vb.net

I want to select text in richtextbox from point a to b like in html format code red> to /red> soo that would be like this: This is a red>message/red> that means it should select from point a that is red> to point b that is /red> then the message word will be selected how can i do that? Thanks.

My latest code that i tried:

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("<red>") Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Find("<red>").ToString
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = RichTextBox1.Find("</red>").ToString
            MessageBox.Show("Format DETECTED!")
        End If
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: what have you tried? I would look at searching the text for the occurance of your start point and store the character count of this point the continue to search for your end point and store the character count of this point. Then all you need is to extract the character between the start and end point.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a richtextbox.find i might be able to do it

Comment: Yes i now understand how to get the position of the selectionstart but how do i end the selection? there is no function that would say like selectionend

Comment: i added the latest code i have on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("<red>") Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = CInt(RichTextBox1.Find("<red>").ToString)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = CInt(RichTextBox1.Find("</red>").ToString)
            RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Find("<red>") + "<red>".Length, RichTextBox1.Find("</red>") - (RichTextBox1.Find("<red>") + "<red>".Length))
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            MessageBox.Show("Format DETECTED!")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked you saved me a lot of time.